# VSCode Java Disable Argument Helper

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image]

I don't want to see these method argument helper kind of texts appearing in my Java projects. They confuse me. How can I disable this feature?

Comment: change setting `inlayHints`

Comment: Yes guys, thank you. I didn't even know what it is called.

Comment: This is the [relevant PR](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/2354) for the inline hints for Java, it has just been updated recently

Comment: VS.Code users who reject common IDE features possibly should turn to Notepad - at the cost of readability. When passing variables instead of static values, the inline hints are usually also gone.